# Is it possible to take an IIS7 site offline, with a 503 message?

Tags: iis-7

is it possible to turn off / make offline, a website on IIS7 BUT it has a maintenance page 'sorry, we're offline' with a status 503?

I know the app_offline.html page does this BUT it reports a 404, not a 503.

Can this be done another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a page in ASP which returns a 503 and use it instead of app_offline.html?